# Fetch event details from google calendar android

Tags: android, calendar, google-calendar-api

I am developing an android app , where I want to fetch and display the event details from the users google calendar. How can I achieve this?. I would be of greta help if you could point me in the right direction.

Please help! thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code to get calender events from device, it is working code.

```
private void getCalenderEvents() {
        Cursor cursor =context.getContentResolver().query(Uri.parse("content://com.android.calendar/events"),
                new String[] { "calendar_id", "title", "description", "dtstart", "dtend", "eventLocation" }, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        // fetching calendars name
        String CNames[] = new String[cursor.getCount()];

    for (int i = 0; i < CNames.length; i++) {

        rowDataEvents = new HashMap<String, String>();

        String eventTitle = cursor.getString(1);
        String eventStartDate = cursor.getString(3);
        String eventEndDate = cursor.getString(4));
        String eventDescription = cursor.getString(2);
        String eventLocation = cursor.getString(5);


        cursor.moveToNext();

    }
    cursor.close();
}
```

Comment: Hi Pratik. I resolved my issue using a similar kind of code.But, I have an issue for device above ICS versions(above 4.0), I am not able to fetch calendar event details for device above ICS. It would be of great help if you could help me out with it. Thanks in advance!